# Why isn't jQuery seeing my plugin's method?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using Barrating 5 star jQuery plugin. For some reason I am getting error:

> .barrating is not a function

Below is my code. I have included all js and css files. Let me know if you need more details.

**EDIT**: I have added css/js declarations

```
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.css">
  <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/search.js"></script>

  <script src="<?php echo asset_url(); ?>/newweb/jquery-bar-rating-master/dist/jquery.barrating.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/tracking.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/badge.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- NProgress -->
    <link href="<?php echo asset_url(); ?>/warehouseadmin/vendors/nprogress/nprogress.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='<?php echo asset_url(); ?>/newweb/jquery-bar-rating-master/dist/themes/fontawesome-stars.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
 <select  class='rating' id='rating_<?php echo $waybill; ?>' data-id='rating_<?php echo $waybill; ?>'>
                            <option value="1" >1</option>
                            <option value="2" >2</option>
                            <option value="3" >3</option>
                            <option value="4" >4</option>
                            <option value="5" >5</option>
                        </select>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('.rating').barrating({
            theme: 'fontawesome-stars',
            onSelect: function(value, text, event) {

                // Get element id by data-id attribute
                var el = this;
                var el_id = el.$elem.data('id');

                // rating was selected by a user
                if (typeof(event) !== 'undefined') {

                    var split_id = el_id.split("_");

                    var postid = split_id[1];  // postid

                    // AJAX Request
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'rating_ajax.php',
                        type: 'post',
                        data: {postid:postid,rating:value},
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function(data){
                            // Update average
                            var average = data['averageRating'];
                            $('#avgrating_'+postid).text(average);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    });

    </script>
```

Comment: Have you actually linked to the library js file? Like did you look at the resulting source code and clicked on the link to see that it does open the file?

Comment: _I have included all js and CSS files._ you must show us those declarations

Comment: I have added declarations now.

Comment: I assume you are missing jsImport like this: <script src="jquery.barrating.min.js"></script>

Comment: @Beri I updated my code.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki updated my code... the code is in local machine so cannot have cloud url

Comment: @uom-pgregorio updated my code.

Comment: After you load the page on your browser, press `CTRL + U` and then click on the link `/newweb/jquery-bar-rating-master/dist/jquery.barrating.min.js` it may not be linking to the file properly.

Comment: Can you include/check the HTML **output** (ie view-source or inspect).  Showing the code with `<?php` tags just makes us *assume* the php variable is wrong.

Comment: Also check the browser network tab as you load the page.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing [JQuery plugin import](http://antenna.io/demo/jquery-bar-rating/examples/).

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.barrating.min.js"></script>
```

This import needs to be placed before your code.

In my opinion your import url might be broken.

```
<script src="<?php echo asset_url(); ?>/newweb/jquery-bar-rating-master/dist/jquery.barrating.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Check in your browser console if this resources (jquery.barrating.min.js) is added to your page, or is there a 404 warning. Simply click on it in web-console, and check if something is returned.

Comment: Out of curiousity, why you import barrating plugin different than jQuery? Both are static libraries, so they should be in same sources, imported in same way.

Answer (score 0):

Before using the js library, make sure you called the needed libraries with following lines :

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.barrating.min.js"></script>
```

Note that you need to include the jQuery library **before** the barrating library.